# Generate a simple C# class from XML

Tags: c#, xml

Are there any good tools to generate a simple C# class from xml.  I have tried XML spy but that takes the data into account and creates a far too complex class structure.

All I want is basically a class for each element and properties for each sub element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool that comes with Visual Studio, but it requires a schema - the schema can be inferred from the XML anyway:

http://sharpertutorials.com/using-xsd-tool-to-generate-classes-from-xml/

The tool is called xsd.exe and you can get to it via the Visual Studio command prompt:

```
xsd.exe /?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `xsd.exe` tool to generate a XML Schema (XSD) and use that to create the class.

http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/xmlserialization/XSDToCls.aspx